# Simple, fast, light GNOME-like CPU/RAM/NETWORK/DISK monitor for taskbar/tray on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, monitoring, network-monitor, system-monitor

There [are many](https://listoffreeware.com/best-free-cpu-temperature-monitor-software-windows/) hardware monitors that exist for Windows, but I am looking for something a bit different.

When I was a Linux user, I appreciated the [system monitor applet](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/08/alternative-system-monitor-applet-for.html) very much.

Its advantage over more sophisticated tools is that if you do software development it can help you quickly peek into the state of the system without switching any windows, launching any apps or switching to desktop. You can just look at the tray and say "Okay, my disk-intensive Python script is still running, no need to check it in the terminal". It's like [htop](https://hisham.hm/htop/), but you don't even need to click anything, the widget is always there.

I am looking for something similar on Windows 10.

Basically, it should be a system tray applet that shows graphs of hardware components performance.